# Is it possible to choose uniformly from $(0,1)$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Can a method be constructed to choose one number uniformly from $(0,1)$?

It has been argued that an event which is possible can have zero probability - such as the probability of selecting any given number when selecting uniformly from $(0,1)$.

But I hold that an event with zero probability can never happen, and therefore I conclude that it is impossible to choose uniformly from  $(0,1)$.

Can a method be constructed to choose uniformly from $(0,1)$?  I've a feeling that if there is a method, there's no guarantee it ever stops.

Comment: What is a 'method'?

Comment: I think in theory, you can draw uniformly, yes. In practice, however, you can not construct such an algorithm/method. But then again, neither is there a practical method to choose uniformly from $\{0,1\}$, even though this set only contains two elements. :)

Comment: Which is the area of a line? Yet it is not impossible for a line to exist...

Comment: I think we can choose uniformly in $(0,1)$ with a generator of (pseudo) random numbers. That the probably is zero does not imply that it cant be done. As an example of mechanical pseudorandom generator can be a disc that we can rotate randomly.

Comment: @Stefan I think your question cuts to the heart of the problem.  How about as a starter for ten, a method is any set of events lying in-between a start with no point chosen uniformly randomly from an infinite number of points and and an end *with* some point chosen uniformly randomly from an infinite number of points. Not sure if that helps?

Comment: @Masacroso how does that work? How do we translate rotations into a number? Every method I can come up with has to be a "possibly never stopping" method.

Comment: @Robert the mechanical method that I propose is not truly random just pseudo-random (as any real and non-theoretic method) as it approximate numbers. In the real world you cant access to all numbers on $(0,1)$ just some ones. Then in the proposed mechanical method you put a mark in a disc, rotate it, and approximate the new angle with respect to some reference. Now, with the approximated angle, you can make it proportional to some number in the interval $[a,b]$, by example multiply your angle by $(b-a)/2\pi$ (for angle in radians) and add the result to $a$.

Comment: It could be argued that it is impossible to do anything.  A more mathematical Question would set out the operations (on numbers?) which are allowed, and then ask if something is possible using those allowed operations.

Comment: @hardmath I was initially inclined to say you are allowed to start with some random number as a seed (which can be random but not assumed uniformly selected or unbiased), and then you are allowed to apply any deterministic mathematical operation to that number repetitively, which can stop after random time. But it must stop.

Comment: Purely uniform random numbers cannot be drawn from a computer.  But a uniform random sequence can be approximated by pseudorandom number genreating algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "method" you mean an algorithm (that can be implemented on a computer), then obviously the answer is "**no**" for the trivial reason that computers cannot deal with real numbers, since there are uncountably many reals but only countably many finite strings, which are all that a computer can deal with.

Furthermore, it does not help to restrict to computable reals, because it is just impossible to define a uniform distribution on computable reals. Basically, each must have zero probability because there are infinitely many of them, but then countable additivity implies that their total probability is zero.

> But I hold that an event with zero probability can never happen, and therefore I conclude that it is impossible to choose uniformly from $(0,1)$.

So, yes, in the real world you can never hope of choosing a uniform random real from $(0,1)$, even if you can somehow obtain unbiased random coin flips.

---

That said, the mathematical notion of probability and possibility is not the same as any real-world notion. For example, mathematically it is possible to have an **infinite** sequence of fair coin flips, and hence it is possible for the entire sequence to consist of heads even though that sequence has zero probability. It does not conflict with actually tossing a fair coin in real life (even if there is a fair coin), because we can never toss it infinitely many times.

**Mathematical** probability is of course based on mathematical definitions, so it is largely irrelevant whether statements in probability theory have a meaningful interpretation in the real world. It is actually not so bad for countable discrete processes such as the coin flip. A probability of zero for a class of sequences means that in the real world you can be sure of eventually escaping that class. For instance, you can be sure that eventually the coin will come up tails, even though you cannot predict when that happens and may have to wait an indeterminable amount of time.

Comment: In case the first paragraph is not clear, **nobody** can specify every possible real number, simply because there are uncountably many reals and only countably many possible descriptions in any practical language. One must fix the language in advance, and the language necessarily involves finite strings from a finite alphabet, otherwise we cannot use it to communicate.

Comment: A computer could choose $\pi$ by answering for example "The ratio of a circle's diameter to its circumference". But I agree all outcomes couldn't be possible. But I struggle to accept that a coin can be considered fair, even **mathematically**, if it's flipped *infinitely* without coming up heads. If we go to infinity, it means there is no limit to how many times we flipped it and always came up tails. This must mean that either it wasn't a fair coin, or the sample was biased. Is there no argument like **infinite number of unbiased samples is the population**?

Comment: @RobertFrost: You have to stop trying to impose your intuition on any mathematical object... Mathematical objects are constructed entirely within the chosen foundational system. As I said clearly, mathematical probability is based on a mathematical definition, and discrete random variables such as a fair coin flip are quite trivial mathematical objects.

Comment: Fair comment, and I have studied probability theory to quite a high level (at university). But the point is I'm not trying to learn it for its own sake, I'm trying to apply it to a halting problem and trying to understand whether there is under some circumstances an argument akin to *probabilistic method* by which halting problems can be deemed to stop based on there being a non-zero probability of stopping.  It's in my nature to probe deeply at specific details.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Yes that's the very purpose of my last part of my last paragraph, to assert that at least for ideal processes with (countably) infinite steps, zero probability in probability theory actually does imply something in the real-world; namely assurance that it eventually leaves the class. So you would say for example that if you have a program that has access to independent fair coin flips (unsurprisingly called probabilistic Turing machines; see Wikipedia) and flips until it gets a head, then indeed we can say for sure that it eventually halts.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for (in my previous question - I think you know the one), thanks.

Comment: @RobertFrost: I don't think I know which one. As I said, this real-world interpretation has **nothing** to do with the truth value of mathematical statements. Again taking the coin flipping example, my last comment above does **not** imply that it is mathematically impossible for the sequence of coin clips to be all heads. To see why it is stupid to use this kind of reasoning, consider two independent infinite sequences of coin flips. With probability **one** the second is distinct from the first but this does not imply the first can never be obtained; after all you obtained it!!

Comment: Agreed, but its sequence of 1's and 0's has to be defined, and it is also a fact that there is no way to choose that definition uniformly randomly.

Comment: @RobertFrost: I don't know what you're getting at now; we are **not** choosing a random definition; that makes no sense. Probability theory permits us to easily define the sequences I have described, as well as prove that they are almost surely distinct. That's all there is to say.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Not only we can't exclude the possibility of a real-world process that produces fair coin flips, we statistically seem to be able to obtain such a process (used in hardware RNGs) or at least something very close, in which case probability theory **does apply** to it and tells us that any two sequences thus generated will surely be eventually different, despite both occurring exactly once due to the generation process.